# Acceder a una variable inicializada en un método desde otra clase

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Cómo puedo acceder al valor de una variable que se inicializó dentro de un método?

Quiero acceder al valor que tenga la variable **lColor** para utilizarla en otra clase pero no se guarda ningún valor.

Lo que trato de hacer es seleccionar un elemento de un combobox que representará un tema para mi programa, y cuando seleccione uno, la variable **lColor** tendrá un color dependiendo del tema que se elija, y ese color lo quiero usar en otras clases pero no me funciona.

¿cómo lo puedo solucionar? ¿o hay otra forma de hacerlo?

```
namespace SICIDES
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public SolidColorBrush lColor;

        public Color blanco = Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        public Color verde = Color.FromRgb(110, 251, 110);
        public Color morado = Color.FromRgb(219, 76, 254);

        private void seleccion(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            handle = !cmb.IsDropDownOpen;
            Handle();
        }
        private bool handle = true;
        private void DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (handle) Handle();
            handle = true;
        }

        private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
            handle = !cmb.IsDropDownOpen;
            Handle();
        }

        public void Handle()
        {
            switch (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last())
            {
                case "Por defecto":
                    lColor = new SolidColorBrush(blanco);
                    break;

                case "Colorido":
                    lColor = new SolidColorBrush(verde);
                    break;

                case "Tema claro":
                    lColor = new SolidColorBrush(morado);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class Datos : Window
    {
    public Datos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cambiaColor();
    }

    MainWindow m = new MainWindow();

    void cambiaColor()
    {
        label.Foreground = m.lColor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo mejor sería declarar la variable **lColor** como estática y en otra clase como en la clase que agrega visual studio App.cs, así se guardarán los valores que le vayas pasando y solo tendrás que acceder a ella mediante **App.lColor**.

Saludos!